# resize image without image quality reduction

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

In web design , it's usually needed to design an image for example in Photoshop and then use multiple sizes of it.

but I don't understand something here :
When I resize the image (PNG or JPG) and **reduce** the dimensions of that in Photoshop , the image quality extremely gets reduced and the edges become messy while resizing the image in a simple software like Microsoft Paint gives a really better output!

So what's the reason ? Is there a trick in Photoshop for image resizing which I've missed?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:** I resize in this way : image > image size , then enter new dimensions , all of checkboxes are checked , and have tried all of resample modes including **Bicubic sharper**

**UPDATE2:** for example , try reducing google logo dimensions , [Google logo](http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png) , and tell me how you do it without decreasing quality. When I try to do it with PhotoShop, it gots fuzzy , please help

Comment: I have always found Photoshop to be superior to MSPaint.  What are the steps that you performed in Photoshop to do the resize?  What options did you select in each dialog?  Would you edit your question and provide additional details?

Comment: Photoshop IS superior to MS Paint. Adobe makes a lot of R&D regarding image processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your example with the Google logo: The logo has an indexed color palette. If you reduce the dimensions of an indexed image in Photoshop, Photoshop uses the same color index table for the smaller image. Thus, the resultuing image looks crappy.

You must convert the original image from indexed color to RGB with at least 8 bit (per R, G, B). Then resize the image, it will look good. Finally, you will have to convert that RGB image back to indexed color (if you need that).

Comment: Works great! but can you tell me which mode is preferred to use in web pages? indexed color or RGB?

Comment: I prefer indexed color for logos, icons, typeface images. Everything else (mostly photos) is saved as RGB. I use GIF (256 colors) and JPG for RGB/8bit images. If I need transparency I use PNG 32 bit with alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop allows more tweaking with in turn could allow for undesired results.
http://www.sitepoint.com/resize-an-image-in-photoshop/

Comment: I read this article before and it suggests using Bicubic **sharper** mode which doesn't help as mentioned in question edit...

Comment: Which version of PS are you using?

Comment: The CS5 Photoshop version